# Reduce screen space for "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?"

Tags: feature-request, questions, profile-page, user-interface

I find that the messages

> Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?

take too much screen space. E.g. I only see 3 questions on a [user profile's question list page](https://patents.stackexchange.com/users/3789/franck-dernoncourt?tab=questions&sort=newest) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20221009224429/https://patents.stackexchange.com/users/3789/franck-dernoncourt?tab=questions&sort=newest)) at a time:

[image]

Feature request: reduce screen space for  "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?"

---

Same issue when browsing via phone:

[image]

Comment: It would probably be best to reduce the bottom-margin on that banner, and the height of it.